# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present Java 8 Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I got this. But my list is not empty and they have element with code "ADPL". Why this return me NoSuchElement ?

```
String retour = CodeExecutionChaine.A.getCode();
    if (!lstChaines.isEmpty()) {
      retour = lstChaines.stream()
                         .filter(t -> t.getNomChaine() == Chaines.ADPL.getCode())
                         .map(Chaine::getStatutChaine)
                         .findFirst()
                         .orElse(CodeExecutionChaine.A.getCode());
```

The enum Chaines

```
public enum Chaines {

  ADPL("ADPL"),
  ADIL("ADIL"),
  ADSL("ADSL");

  private String code = "";

  Chaines(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getCode() {
    return this.code;
  }

}
```

This is the same for CodeExecutionChaine

Comment: Can you please post your exception with stack trace?

Comment: Is `Chaines.ADPL.getCode()` a reference to a `String`?`

Comment: Yes and t.getNomChaine() is a String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `t -> t.getNomChaine() == Chaines.ADPL.getCode()` to `t -> t.equals(Chaines.ADPL.getCode())`.

`==` checks for identity. Therefore, `==` will result into `true` only if two references point to the same object. On the other hand, `equals` checks for `equality`. Two references that don't point to the same object but have similar `properties` are still considered equal. You get a `NoSuchElementException` because you used `==` to `filter` your `Stream` which resulted in zero elements satisfying the condition.

Comment: It's working!!! Why it's the difference between ? Why the == doesn't work?

Comment: Exactly zero elements. But `CodeExecutionChaine.A.getCode()` should be returned in that case.  Why NoSuchElementException?

Comment: @saka1029 None of the methods that you use can directly throw that `Exception`. Please post your stack trace in your question for further analysis. Also confirm that you are showing us the same code that you are facing the issue with.